# Concatenating multiple arrays to be inserted into a mongo aggregation query using php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to create an aggregation query for mongo within php. However I need to dynamically create the unwind operations. I am trying to do this within a for loop shown below.

```
for($j = 0; $j < $step; $j++) {

    if($j == 0) {
        $compare = '$steps'; //On first loop, instantiate the first level to unwind
    } else {
        $compare = $compare.".steps"; //Concatenate every next level to unwind
    }
    $wind = $wind.array('$unwind' => $compare); //Need a way to concatenate arrays

}
```

As you can see, I have tried to concatenate the arrays on every iteration, but this does not work.

Is there a way I can automate the creation of a variable containing the arrays below, depending on a number given for the number of unwinds needed - in the example below, the number is 3.

```
$wind = array('$unwind' => '$steps'), array('$unwind' => '$steps.steps'), array('$unwind' => '$steps.steps.steps'); //What I want end variable output to be
```

Final desired aggregation query below.

```
$query = array(   
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "name" => $process['name'], $query => $title
        )
    ),
    $wind,
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                 "_id" => 0,
                 "steps.title" => 1,
            )
        ),
);
```

EDIT: Solved, I used [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to insert each part into the array. Seems I was making the problem way too complicated for myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). This function will merge your arrays. Example:

```
$wind = array();
for($j = 0; $j < $step; $j++) {

    if($j == 0) {
        $compare = '$steps'; //On first loop, instantiate the first level to unwind
    } else {
        $compare = $compare.".steps"; //Concatenate every next level to unwind
    }
    $wind = array_merge($wind, array('$unwind' => $compare)); //Need a way to concatenate arrays

}
```

Code is untested, let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Apologies, this hasn't exactly done what I needed. It seems that on each loop it overwrites the array currently stored, rather than adding an extra array on. On inspection of the documentation, this is what array_merge is supposed to do, however I need the variable to store each array.

Comment: If you want an array of arrays, then you can do something like array_merge($wind, array(array('$unwind' => $compare)))